# How i can trasform an object in an array of object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object

{
Bamboo: 7,
Eucalipto: 1,
Frassino: 2,
Ulivo: 1
}

I want to trasform this object in an array of object

[
{
plantName: Bamboo,
quantity: 7
},
{
plantName: Eucalipto,
quantity: 1
},
{
plantName: Frassino,
quantity: 2
},
{
plantName: Ulivo,
quantity: 1
},
]

Comment: you can use Object.entries and combine it with map.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Here's what I might do.

```
const dataObject = { Bamboo: 7, Eucalipto: 1, Frassino: 2, Ulivo: 1 };

const dataArray = Object.keys( dataObject ).map( ( key ) => {
    return { 'plantName': key, 'quantity': dataObject[key] };
} );

console.log( dataArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the entries of the object, creating a new object with each key-value pair.

```js
let obj = { Bamboo: 7, Eucalipto: 1, Frassino: 2, Ulivo: 1 };
let res = Object.entries(obj).map(([plantName,quantity])=>({plantName, quantity}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are many different ways of doing this. But here are the basic steps as I learned them when I was starting out.

1. [Create an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).
2. [Iterate over the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement).
3. [Create a new object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics), and assign the `key` of the input object to "plantName", and the `value` of the input object to "quantity".
4. [Add that new object to an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Here's an old-school way of achieving this:

```js
const obj = { Bamboo: 7, Eucalipto: 1, Frassino: 2, Ulivo: 1 };

// Create an array
const arr = [];

// Iterate over the object
for (const key in obj) {

  // Create a new object assigning the key
  // to `plantName`, and the value to `quantity`
  const newObj = {
    plantName: key,
    quantity: obj[key]
  };

  // Add the new object to the array
  arr.push(newObj);
}

// Et voila!
console.log(arr);
```

Once you understand the basic concepts then you can start to introduce more complex methods like [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries), and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but if you're just starting out with JavaScript this is probably more than enough to help you understand the process.